# How to code excel cells so that when you input data it automatically calculates what you enter + the previous cell

Tags: excel, math

I hope this question isn't too obvious for this, I tried google but didn't know how to word this correctly so I thought i'd ask here. I used to use Excel a lot more but haven't in a while so I don't remember anything really. (Sorry if I don't use the right terms and if it's very wordy but I'll try my best to explain what I'm asking for)

Basically, I am making a spreadsheet on my spotify data (using lastfm to get the data)

The top row has every date of the year and the first column shows the Artist names. What I want to do is make it so that if for example; on January 1st I listened to "Artist A" 12 times, i'd put 12 into January 1st, but if I listened to "Artist A" 2 times on January 2nd, I wouldn't show 2 I'd show 14 as that'd be the total amount I'd listened to that artist so far, and so on for each artist and date. I don't want to manually calculate everything, obviously in the example it was easy to simply figure out 12 + 2 but when it gets to larger numbers it'd just be time consuming to type into every cell "=12+2" I want to be able to select every cell and make it so that in future if I typed a number into the cell, it would display the sum of that number + whatever is displayed in the previous cell in that row.

I hope I've explained what I'm asking well enough.

Example of the data (screenshot):

[image]

Comment: Define previous cell. Is that always previous column? As in column-1

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do something manually that would be easily done with formulas or pivot table. Perhaps include an example from the raw data.

Comment: @Andreas The previous cell would be one on the previous column (to the left) in the same row, also yeah I don't know how to do formulas which is why I posted the question. because i'd like to use the right one for what I'm doing (I've edited the post to include a screenshot of what the data looks like)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the easiest way is to create a new sheet and copy all artists (column A only) to that sheet to the "same cells" on that sheet.
And do the same with the dates (row 2)

Then in cell B3 add the following formula:

```
=SUM(OriginalSheetName!$B3:B3)
```

Then drag this formula to the right then down.
Now your new sheet should be what you want.

Example:
The top table is your original and the lower is the calculated accumulated table.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I needed! This is going to save me a lot of time and now at the end it should be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried
=SUM(CELL1+CELL2

Comment: Yes I have, but then I think I would have to type that code into each cell manually, I was hoping I could select all the cells I need and type something in so that each cell did that sum automatically, I'm not sure if it's possible

Comment: no you dont have to type it manually into every cell, click on the cell where you have formula, and on the right corner of the cell you will se dot, using your mouse you can scroll down that formula to other cells which will automatically do same stuff on selected cells + automaitcally select cells on that "row" next to it. like if first its CELL1+CELL2 it will switch automatically to ROW2 > CELL1+CELL2 like this see picutre
https://i.ibb.co/DkBZB59/imgur.png